# corel draw cdr to html website

Tags: html, css

hello i will need some of your lights in here.i have these cdr files and i want to make them html website.i have managed to make the cdr into jpg and then by mapping made them into some kind of a page.The thing is that it loads differendly in monitors and also i am unable to make it look nice.any suggestions of how i can make this jpg into a website since i am not really good in coding or at least make it look good in all kinds of monitor?
thanks in advance [my corel draw[][1]](http://ammoyiali.com)

Comment: just to make clear what i am asking is the HOW does one makes all that jpg into a real website....

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Change line 21 which set the height as 99% in to this:

`height: initial !important;`